# What is the word for this effect - things are not normally noticed until those things come in to the news and people fear/are looking for them

Tags: word-choice

For instance. I've never really paid attention to white vans, but when the DC sniper was at large and they stated that he's probably shooting from a white van, white vans seemed to appear out of no where and be around every corner!

Comment: Seems like this question should be on EL&U.

Comment: Agreed, this is off-topic. @KitFox, since you're a mod over there, shall I send this to EL&U?

Comment: @Neil Yes, let's.

Comment: @KitFox - Done!